# Sqlite3: Location of the data base file in the file system

Tags: sqlite

I am starting to get familiar with the sqlite. I am currently using SQLite version 3.13.0 2016-05-18.

I created a test data base called "test.db" as follows:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

And then, I created a table called "employees" in the database as follow:

```
create table employees(id integer primary key, name text);
```

Then after I added the following entry to the table:

```
insert into employees(id, name) values(410,'test');
```

Everything works as expected. But, somehow I can not find where my test database file is located in the file system. Any idea where that .db file is located? I am in windows system.

Comment: I tried to check the databases. But, it does not show my database file. sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had to save the .db file as follows:

```
.save test.db
```

And, then the .db file appeared in the same directory as SQLite database file is also a regular file.